# SugarCRM connector for Facebook

Tags: facebook, sugarcrm, connector

I am new to Sugar CRM and i would like to develop Facebook connector for community edition.
I could not get any sample code for this.
If anybody know please guide me to develop this connector.

Thanks
Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the various other connections available...

http://www.sugarforge.org/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=facebook&Search=Search

Comment: Thanks jmetric finished this task using basic connector coding with FB php-sdk ......

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM documentation have one example on connectors implementation

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/02_Application_Framework/Connectors/Examples/Creating_A_Custom_Connector

And of course you can search for connectors in GitHub where I find some useful projects like

https://github.com/eggsurplus/Freshbooks

or

https://github.com/eggsurplus/DropboxPidgin